# Service fabric not showing .net core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio-2019, azure-service-fabric

Visual Studio 2019 template for Service Fabric has a drop down to select the dotnet framework. Mine only shows dotnet frameworks and not core. I am able to create other .net core application but not service fabric. Any ideas on what to look for? I have already validated the SDKs are on the computer.

Comment: Have you update visual studio / service fabric SDK to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understand what is happening. The first thing the template creates is the project. Since my development machine's OS is Windows, it requires me to use .Net framework. Once inside the project I am able to create individual .Net Core Applications. I haven't been able to find documentation that explains this. I was initially following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app) which seemed a little out of date or for some other reason was missing the step for setting up the projects framework version. I don't know how the projects framework is used in either case.